# Forcing password on login with IAP and restrict domain

Tags: django, security, google-cloud-platform, google-iap

I've set up a Django/python web application running on Google Cloud Platform's Kubernetes Engine pods, and secured by GCP's Identity-Aware Proxy.

It all works great, but there are two things I'm not sure how to accomplish.

1) How can I restrict the users to a specific domain, just like the hd=my_domain.com URL parameter does on OAuth2 logging in? That makes the sign-in page only show emails with that domain in the list to click on.

2) How can I enforce that the user logs in with a password, instead of just simply clicking on the account? This is just like when you go to admin.google.com, or security.google.com and even though you're logged in, it forces a password. I know how to go to /*gcp*/clear_login_cookie to enforce a new login session when I want to log them out, but not sure how to enforce a password is entered. This I believe is called the "user presence test."

Any help is greatly appreciated, I've poured through documentation and have searched various ways on Stack Overflow to no avail.

Comment: When I go to Manage this Domain, I get a window that requires a password. This is exactly what I want to enforce when the Django session has expired or they are logging in for the first time. The message shows this above a password feld: "To continue, first verify it's you"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these items are on our roadmap, though I can't offer a specific timeline.

I don't see an entry in Issue Tracker for either of these. I'll try to remember to add that next week (at which point I'll add the links here), or you can do it yourself: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190831&template=1162609

Thanks for the suggestion, and sorry I don't have a better answer for you!
  --Matthew, Cloud IAP engineering

Comment: Alrighty, thanks, Matthew. I submitted a request. 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123730535